# bootstrap table responsive text wrap for mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap newbie here.  I'm using Bootstrap's table-responsive class and I would like text wrapping in the first column.  Can this be done?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table table-striped" >
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>
                                Event Date - Type
                     </th>
                     <th>
                                Company - Event State
                    </th>

                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>        
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                        blah1 blah2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        blah3 blah4
                    </td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Current problem with table-striped class, no text wrap first column:
[image: no text wrap]

I want it to look like this using table-striped class with wrap text:

[image]

Comment: Not really sure what you want to achive. Text is wrapping as far as I know

Comment: Shubert, when I use table-responsive class, first column text doesn't wrap.  Here is the image: [link](http://imgur.com/NIo8oUd)    If I use table class other than table-responsive class, I can get the first column text to wrap.  See this: [link](http://imgur.com/wRkFQx1)    I want to use table-responsive class with the first column text wrapping. Any other thoughts?